# Class method returns last made of class, C++

Tags: c++

So for school I have to make a Node class that holds a time and a number (it's used for an insertion sort later). I'm still new to C++ so I'm probably doing something wrong here, but whenever I call my GetNumber() method, it will return only the number of the last Node that was made. My code is below:

Node.cpp

```
#include "Node.h"
int n, t;

Node::Node(int number, int time)
{
    n = number;
    t = time;
}


Node::~Node(void)
{
}

int Node::GetTime(void)
{
    return t;
}

int Node::GetNumber(void)
{
    return n;
}
```

And in main:

```
Node f(123, GetTickCount());
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){}
Node g(124, GetTickCount());
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){}
Node d(111, GetTickCount());
cout << f.GetNumber() << "  " << f.GetTime()<<endl;
cout << g.GetNumber() << "  " << g.GetTime()<<endl;
cout << d.GetNumber() << "  " << d.GetTime()<<endl;
```

And the output:

```
111  168921894
111  168921894
111  168921894
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int n, t;
```

You are declaring `n` and `t` as global variables - they don't belong to any particular object. All `Node`s will see the same `n` and `t` objects.

You should be declaring these as members of `Node`:

```
class Node {
  // ...
  int n, t;
  // ...
};
```

Comment: So where would I put class Node { ... int n,t ... };

Comment: @user3280133 Well what do you have in `Node.h`? Presumably you already have a `Node` definition? So you already have something like `class Node { ... };` and you just need add the declarations of `int n, t;` in that definition.

Comment: #pragma once
class Node
{
public:
 Node(int number, int time);
 ~Node(void);
 int GetNumber(void);
 int GetTime(void);
};

Comment: So my class variables go in Node.h, not Node.cpp??

Comment: @user3280133: Yes, all class members must be declared in the class definition.

Comment: @user3280133 Everything declared within `class Node { ... };` belongs to the class, so yes.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is you are using file level variables as the storage for all `Node` values.  Instead you need to store them as instance fields in the type

```
class Node { 
  ...
private:
  int n;
  int t;
};
```

Once those fields are defined delete the declaration at the top of the file for `n` and `t`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define "n" and "t" in the class and so they are global and only the last one to change is the one that is relevant.